# Cant create good match query in mongodb for getting doc that contain doc with "name"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to write a query that will only return documents that contain a subdocument with a specific name

For example:

**First document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df38168358d1e3cec1af759"),
    "sysInfo" : {
        "User" : "blatman",
        "OS" : "Windows",
        "GPU" : "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti  ",
        "CPU" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz  ",
        "RAM" : 65478
    },
    "performance" : {
        "step1" : {
            "1" : {
                "RT" : 502.41438310258566
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Second document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df38168358d1e3cec1af759"),
    "sysInfo" : {
        "User" : "blatman",
        "OS" : "Windows",
        "GPU" : "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti  ",
        "CPU" : "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz  ",
        "RAM" : 65478
    },
    "performance" : {
        "step2" : {
            "1" : {
                "RT" : 505.41438310258566
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want only the first document to be returned after "match" (document with subdocument "step1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) with either a query or the aggregation framework. Guessing you are looking to use the aggregation framework since you mentioned `match`.

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "performance.step1": {
        $exists: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PTISJaZDbas)

Comment: Thank you so much!